# vim [filename] not opening file in Ubuntu bash

Tags: bash, vim

I am attempting to open a c file using Vim in Ubuntu from the bash command line, but it's not opening.

I want to open the following file:

```
~/Documents/ex8.c
```

using the following command:

```
~/Documents$ vim ex8.c
```

I definitely installed Vim; however when I run the command it just displays the prompt again and doesn't give a hoot. BTW, I also tried Google, but I found nothing useful.

Being new to Linux, I might be doing something wrong; I appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Interesting... If you try to open other files with vim, does it work?  Have you checked your permissions on the file? (`ls -la ~/Documents/ex8.c`)
As per default vim-tiny is installed on every Ubuntu.  Usually that enough, but I usually install full vim any way, but that is almost certainly not what's going on here.

Comment: Also try the command `whereis vim` to see where vim is located.  Mine looks lik this: `vim: /usr/bin/vim.basic /usr/bin/vim.tiny /usr/bin/vim /etc/vim /usr/bin/X11/vim.basic /usr/bin/X11/vim.tiny /usr/bin/X11/vim /usr/share/vim /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz`

Comment: @jawtheshark I get pretty much the same result for **whereis vim**. Also, I know I have permissions because I can open it in **gedit**.

Comment: Curiouser, and curiouser... 
I just tested.  If you only have read-only, vi opens the file read-only, if you have no permission it still starts up and says "permission denied".  So it definitely isn't that.
Perhaps vi dumps core?  Is there a file called core in the directory where you launched vi and never got any result.  That said, normally it should say something along the lines "segmentation fault, core dumped".

You haven't told me whether vi opens other files.

Comment: Hell, what happens if you just start `vim` without any files?

Comment: @jawtheshark absolutely nothing happens...

Comment: Okay, so it definitely is not related to the file you referred to in your question.  Basically, your question comes down to "vim doesn't start".
Try reinstalling it for starters. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim`

Comment: @jawtheshark just reinstalled; nothing doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44132/discussion-between-intellidata-and-jawtheshark).

Comment: I really have to start to guess now.  Can you show me how alternatives is set up?

`ls -la /etc/alternatives/vim`

It should look something like `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Abr 26 15:38 /etc/alternatives/vim -> /usr/bin/vim.basic` where /usr/bin/vim.basic is green.  Green means the symlink is pointing to a valid file.

Comment: @jawtheshark yes, it is green.

Comment: Is there an alias? try `command vim ex8.c`

Comment: @Thomas Zwaagstra Didn't work..

Comment: I don't have the impression the chat works.  Grasping at straws, but can you compare the  md5 of your vim.basic to mine?  `$ md5sum /usr/bin/vim.basic` results in `d4c1912e7af17c552a530b26bfbd1dba  /usr/bin/vim.basic
`

Now, obviously, if we don't have exactly the same version, it will differ. I'm using amd64, don't even bother if you're not using the same architecture.

Comment: @jawtheshark different md5 for me.

Comment: Do you have something funky in ~/.vimrc ? `mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vimrc.bak`

Comment: @Thomas Zwaagstra Thank You! That's exactly what the problem was! Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Converted comment to answer. props to the collective effort though

Comment: @IntelliData You should now compare the newly generated `~/.vimrc` with `~/.vimrc.bak` and see what actually happened to avoid making the same mistake in the future.

Comment: @edwinski I had mistakenly typed :q in the .vimrc file. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have something wrong in your ~/.vimrc, causing vim to quit when it starts. Try moving it to see if that helps.

```
mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vimrc.bak
```

You can also skip all initializations by using `-u NONE`

```
vim -u NONE ~/Documents/ex8.c
```

Documentation:

> ```
>    -u {vimrc}  Use  the  commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations.  All the other initializations are skipped.  Use this to edit a special kind of files.
>                It can also be used to skip all initializations by giving the name "NONE".  See ":help initialization" within vim for more details.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have permission to read the file, or you may not have permission to write to the file and vim may not want to open it in read-only mode. In Linux, file permissions are changed by the `chmod` command. Do this:

1. From `~/Documents/`, type `ls -la ex8.c`, that will list the current permissions for that file.
2. On the far left, there will be 10 characters, each (from 2-10) being
   a permission ('user', 'group' and 'others', with 3 permissions each). 'r' means 'read' permission, 'w' means 'write permission, 'x' means 'execute' permission, and '-' means that permission isn't set.
3. type `sudo chmod a+rw ex8.c`, this will give read-write permission to everybody (all users).
4. type `ls -la ex8.c` again, confirm you have 3 'rw' in those columns.

[See here](http://www.pa.msu.edu/~abdo/unixcc.html) for more info on `chmod`.

Comment: I followed your instructions, with the expected results, but it still does not open. :{